react-native - could not find com.facebook.react:flipper-integration
I am working on a react native app and trying to upgrade the react native version. However, I am facing the issue:
could not find com.facebook.react:flipper-integration

Please let me know if you have any idea. Thank you!

After researching about the issue. I found that Facebook removes com.facebook.react:flipper-integration.
Therefore, we should also remove these lines:

From app/build.gradle

implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")

From MainApplication

import com.facebook.react.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper
ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager)

Clean and rebuild the project


Finally a solution that works! Thank you!
